# Mutex for getter method causes deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

Hi, I wanted to ask what is the best solution for the following problem. (explained below)

I have following memory library code (simplified):

```c
 // struct is opaque to callee
 struct memory {
      void *ptr;
      size_t size;
      pthread_mutex_t mutex;
 };

 size_t memory_size(memory *self)
 {   
      if (self == NULL) {
           return 0;
      }

      {
           size_t size = 0;

           if (pthread_mutex_lock(self->mutex) == 0) {
                size = self->size;
                (void)pthread_mutex_unlock(self->mutex);
           }

           return size;
      }
 }

 void *memory_beginAccess(memory *self)
 {
      if (self == NULL) {
           return NULL;
      }

      if (pthread_mutex_lock(self->mutex) == 0) {
           return self->ptr;
      }

      return NULL;
 }

 void memory_endAccess(memory *self)
 {
      if (self == NULL) {
           return;
      }

      (void)pthread_mutex_unlock(self->mutex);
 }
```

The problem:

```c
 // ....
 memory *target = memory_alloc(100);
 // ....
 {
      void *ptr = memory_beginAccess(target);
      // ^- implicit lock of internal mutex

      operationThatNeedsSize(ptr, memory_size(target));
      // ^- implicit lock of internal mutex causes a deadlock (with fastmutexes)

      memory_endAccess(target);
      // ^- implicit unlock of internal mutex (never reached)
 }
```

So, I thought of three possible solutions:

1.) Use a recursive mutex. (but I heard this is bad practice and should be avoided whenever possible).

2.) Use different function names or a flag parameter:
memory_sizeLocked()
memory_size()

memory_size(TRUE) memory_size(FALSE)

3.) Catch if pthread_mutex_t returns EDEADLK and increment a `deadlock counter` (and decrement on unlock) (Same as recursive mutex?)

So is there another solution for this problem? Or is one of the three solutions above "good enough" ?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Do you have to use the same mutex?

Comment: Yes, because memory operations (such as realloc) can affect size.

Comment: The problem is, I want functions which can be called without a function call to "beginAccess" and within a "beginAccess" and "endAccess" block (when multiple actions are performed).

Answer (score 0):

Use two versions of the same function, one that locks and the other that doesn't. This way you will have to modify the least amount of code. It is also logically correct since, you must know when you are in a critical part of the code or not.

Comment: And how should I name them? (Example: memory_size())

Comment: I have no clou.. (English is not my native language :S)